# Disable the click-anywhere-to-close functionality of paper-dialog and make it persistent

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

The title is pretty much my question.

I have a `<paper-dialog>` that I would like to only be closable/openable by specific elements on the page, however, I do not want it to be modal and would like to have the rest of the page continue to be usable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the tag you wish to disable mouse events you can use the css `pointer-events: none;`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events